# Package igraph0 deprecated and hence not able to access gspan package

Tags: r, igraph

Hi am trying some examples from the book: [Practical Graph mining with R](https://www.crcpress.com/Practical-Graph-Mining-with-R/Samatova-Hendrix-Jenkins-Padmanabhan-Chakraborty/9781439860847) for subgraph mining:

```
library(subgraphMining)
library(igraph)

graph1 = graph.ring(5)
graph2 = graph.ring(6)

database <- array(dim=2)
database[1] <- list(graph1)
database[2] <- list(graph2)

result <- gspan(database, support= "80%")
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error in library(igraph0) : there is no package called ‘igraph0’
```

This is probably because igraph0 is deprecated. So, do we need to tweak the functions in the subgraphMining package for using gspan in R; or is there any other way where I can point out to R that igraph0 is updated to igraph

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

`igraph0` is *not* updated to `igraph` so you shouldn't do that. The key difference between `igraph0` and `igraph` (apart from the fact that `igraph0` is way outdated) is that `igraph0` uses 0-based vertex and edge indices, while `igraph` uses 1-based indices. Simply using `igraph` in place of `igraph0` won't work because packages depending on `igraph0` *expect* vertex indices to start at zero.

The only sensible solution is to ask the maintainers of packages that still depend on `igraph0` to upgrade to `igraph`. Alternatively, you can get `igraph0` from the [archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I used a third party C compiled program and got outputs desired. But I wished to do it in R itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Earnest_learner I am an R user facing the same problem as you did. Could you please expand on how you ran the C implementation of gspan? You could consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Well, I didn't use it in R. I took the data out and used another competing algorithm for subgraph mining called as 'Grami' (refer the authors' paper [here](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol7/p517-elseidy.pdf) and their C Code can be downloaded from their [github page](https://github.com/ehab-abdelhamid/GraMi/)