# No package called igraph0 R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to use "gspan" algorithm using R. I installed and loaded `igraph`.

But when I call "gspan", I get this error:

```
>  results = subdue(graph1);
Error in library(igraph0) : there is no package called ‘igraph0’
```

Could any one give me a solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the CRAN repo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph0/index.html):

> Package ‘igraph0’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/).
>
> This was a transitional package from Mar 2012 to Sept 2013. Packages depending on it ought to have changed to igraph long ago.
>
> Consider using package ‘igraph’ instead.

So this package is no longer available on the CRAN. I'd urge you to consider the suggestion and move to `igraph` instead.

So, just load the package as `library(igraph)` instead of `library(igraph0)`. Since you mentioned you have already installed `igraph`, this should work.

Comment: i changed igraph0 by igraph and i got new error > results = subdue(graph1);
Error in 1:graph1[[1]] : NA/NaN argument

Comment: @user2839986 Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268708/package-igraph0-deprecated-and-hence-not-able-to-access-gspan-package)? Alternatively, you could take the package `igraph0` from the archive. Or does your data have missing values?

Comment: no there's no missing data , changes that i ve made in Script.R by replacint igraph0 == igraph made this prb

Comment: You cannot just simply switch from `igraph0` to `igraph` and expect all the code to work; the key difference between `igraph0` and `igraph` is that vertices and edges in a graph are indexed from zero in `igraph0` and from one in `igraph`. The code in the `gspan` library very likely relies on zero-based vertices and edges, so you have to scan the code of `gspan` carefully and fix the places where zero-based vertices and edges are assumed.

Comment: processInputGspan = function(graphArray, output)
{
 library(igraph)
  for(i in 1:length(graphArray))
 {
  write("XP", outputFile)
  #write vertices
  for(j in 1:graphArray[[i]][[1]])
  {
   write(paste("v", j, "a"), outputFile)
  }
  
}

Comment: here is the code of inputGspan , what can i change except , library (igraph)

Answer (score 0):

igraph0 package is deprecated.

Alternatively, you can get igraph0 from the [archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/).

And searching through this site may be helpful as well. For instance, check here: [Package igraph0 deprecated and hence not able to access gspan package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268708/package-igraph0-deprecated-and-hence-not-able-to-access-gspan-package)